# If $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$ then what is the value of $\det\Delta$?

Tags: determinant, roots, cubics

> If $a,b,c$ are the roots of $ x^3+x^2-2x+1=0$, then what is the value of $\det\Delta$ where:
>   $$\Delta=\begin{bmatrix}
>  c^2    &   b^2  &     2bc-a^2 \\ 2ac-b^2 &  a^2    &   c^2 \\    a^2   &     2ab-c^2  & b^2 \\   \end{bmatrix}$$

The roots are not simply resolvable. So my experience tells me that we need to convert $\Delta$ into a form that contains $a+b+c$ or $ab+bc+ca$ or $abc$.

Since expanding this determinant would be tedious, please suggest a method that doesn't require it.

All help will be appreciated

Comment: Use the rule of SARRUS!

Comment: Is your $(1,1)$ coefficient $a^2$ or $c^2$ ?

Comment: What is the result of your determinant?

Comment: I think in the last line of your determinant is a typo.

Comment: Expand the determinant and see if you find things like $a+b+c$

Comment: he can not find such things since he has a typo!

Comment: @Delta-u I'm sorry it was a typo.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner ^

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For your determinant we get $$ \left( b+a+c \right) ^{2} \left( {b}^{2}-ab-bc-ac+{a}^{2}+{c}^{2}
 \right) ^{2}
$$

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer! Did you expand then factorize? (That's a lot of work)

Comment: Yes i did it by this way!

Comment: I also used the hints above!

Comment: Could this form be obtained in a simpler way? It was asked in a test and we only had 5 minutes to solve it. (It's much harder the first time you see it)